# Justifying "infinitesimals" in differential equations - Arnold

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-forms, infinitesimals

In [Ordinary Differential Equations](https://books.google.it/books/about/Ordinary_Differential_Equations.html?id=JUoyqlW7PZgC&redir_esc=y) Arnold justifies the use of $dx, dy \dots$ in differential equations such as 
\begin{equation}
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{f(y)}{g(x)}
\end{equation}
by saying that the differential 1-forms $g(x)dx$ and $f(y)dy$ are equal on an integral curve of the equation. However, the integral curve (call it $\gamma$) is 2-dimensional, so a parameterization of $\gamma$ would look like $\varphi : [a, b] \to \gamma, \varphi(t) = (\varphi_1(t), \varphi_2(t))$ and the only differential 1-forms for which an integral along $\gamma$ is defined belong to $C\big(\Omega, (\mathbb{R}^2)^{*}\big)$, where $\gamma \subseteq \Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$. So, the integrals of the differential forms $g(x)dx$ and $f(y)dy$ on $\gamma$ cannot be defined, since $f$ and $g$ only take one argument each. This is where I'm stuck.

I thought about a possible work around but it involves tweaking the definition of a differential 1-form on a continuous curve. 
We define the function $\overline{g}(x, y) = g(x)$ and simply integrate as follows:
$$
\int_{\gamma} g(x)dx = \int_{\gamma} \overline{g}(x,y)dx + 0dy
$$
Is it possible that this procedure is what Arnold means?

Comment: Actually, the $1$-forms should be $dx/g(x)$ and $dy/f(y)$. The integral curve is a curve, not $2$-dimensional. You use the parametrization and pull back and get $\varphi^*(dx/g(x)) = \varphi_1’(t)dt/g(\varphi(t))$, etc.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry, I don't get it. You write $g(\varphi(t))$ but also $\varphi_1'(t)$. How many components does $\varphi$ have?

Comment: I'm using your formula in your question. You might want to check out some of my YouTube lectures (linked in my profile) — in particular, the ones on forms, pullback, and line integrals.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check them out!